# .net Process.Start Method not Launching Excel File in Excel 2013 only when launched from whithin excel com addin

Tags: c#, excel-2013, process.start, processstartinfo, comaddin

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() not launching an excel file In Excel 2013 and that too launched from inside excel comaddin.

```
string filename = @"C:\Users\centraluser\AppData\Roaming\STUDIO\CENTRAL\d7c98719-7aa9-4e7e-8fb6- 
   bd5a5b23f560\New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx";
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
processStartInfo.FileName = filename;
var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

It hangs after Process.start  and waits for some time and then returns with a null process value.

While the same file gets launched if I use the same code and try to open the file from a console application.

And all this behavior is only occurring with Excel 2013 only.

Kindly help on the same.

Comment: Any hElp on this please?

Comment: A new Progress i have made in this.
If I try to open the excel in this way -
string filename = @"C:\Users\centraluser\AppData\Roaming\STUDIO\CENTRAL\d7c98719-7aa9-4e7e-8fb6- 
   bd5a5b23f560\New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx";

Process.start("Excel.exe",filename);

then the excel file is opened.Can anything be inferred from this??

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=netframework-4.8):

> Set the UseShellExecute property to specify whether to start the
>   process by using the operating system shell.

Set the `processStartInfo.UseShellExecute` to `true` value.

Comment: Useshellexecute was bydefault true.And problem arises onlyy when launched from inside Excel com addin code and Excel 2013 is used